# Creating Set in F# with elements from 1111 to 6666

Tags: f#, set, sequence

How do i create a Set in F# with elements from 1111 to 6666 without any values being 0, 7 or higher.

E.g. `[1111,1112,1113,1114,1115,1116,1121]`
I'd like to make it a set.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a sequence comprehension:

```
let values = seq {
    for i in 1110 .. 10 .. 6660 do
      for j in 1 .. 6 do
        yield i + j
    }
```

and create a set using `Set.ofSeq` e.g.

```
let s = Set.ofSeq values
```

Comment: and how would i do if i wanted it the integers to set of sets or list of lists. E.g. [[1;1;1;1];[1;1;1;2];[1;1;1;3]] ?

Answer (score 1):

There must be an easier way than:

```
let values = seq {
for a in 1000 .. 1000 .. 6000 do
for b in 100 .. 100 .. 600 do
for c in 10 .. 10 .. 60 do
for d in 1 .. 6 do
    yield a + b + c + d
}
```