# Creating list of lists F#

Tags: list, f#

How would i create a list of lists with elements such as [[1;1;1;1];[1;1;1;2];[1;1;1;3];[1;1;1;4];[1;1;1;5];[1;1;1;6];[1;1;2;1]...[6;6;6;6]] ?

It must be within range 1-6 at every place. But i'm unsure of how to do this.

Comment: where is your attempted solution?

Comment: You could start by adapting the answers to [the question you asked yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469424/creating-set-in-f-with-elements-from-1111-to-6666)

Answer (score 2):

Not nice implementation, but it works

```
let myList = [
    for a in 1..6 do
        for b in 1..6 do
            for c in 1..6 do
                for d in 1..6 do
                    yield [a; b; c ;d]
]
```